# Function template specialization with reference to pointer

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have a template function:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T& value) { bar(value); x = -1; }
```

I want to specialize it for a set of types:

```
template<>
void foo<char>(const char& value) { bar(value); x = 0; }
template<>
void foo<unsigned char>(const unsigned char& value) { bar(value); x = 1; }
```

It works ok. When I compile this:

```
template<>
void foo<char*>(const char*& value) { bar(value); x = 2; }
```

I get an error:

```
error C2912: explicit specialization; 'void foo(const char *&)' is not a specialization of a function template
```

Is it possible to specialize with `char*` pointer type parameter without typedef'ing it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sure. Try this:

```
template<>
void foo<char*>(char* const& value) {...}
```

This is because `const char*` means pointer to `const char`, not a `const` pointer to `char`.

Comment: You could also do this, right?

    `template<>
    void foo<const char*>(const char* const& value) {...}`

This kind of approach works for me, though I'm not finding it necessary to specify `<const char *>` after `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You should generally just avoid function template specializations: you'll have far less problems if you provide non-template overloads instead. Read more: [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: Yes, redesigned to use overloading after realizing it myself.